# Array content isn't updated after System.arraycopy()

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

Maybe someone can tell me why this does not work and why the data in array is not updated after calling setListData??

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


      list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
      list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

      final EditText EditMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWebSite);
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String website = EditMessage.getText().toString();

                //String returnString = loaddata(website);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updating Information",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                setListData();

                BaseAdapter la = (BaseAdapter)list1.getAdapter();
                ((BaseAdapter) la).notifyDataSetChanged() ;

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            }
        });



private void setListData()
    {
        String array2[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",    "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
         System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of you swapped the params for
[`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

As you can see, it is first the **source** and then the **destination**.

Currently you are copying the content of `array` into the local temporary `array2`.

Comment: after the change it blows up?

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(713): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Check carefully the arguments (the length and postions) you pass to the method. And check the length of the two arrays you are using.